# Show that there is only one endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2Y + XY^2 - XY)$ that is an automorphism on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2Y + XY^2 - XY).$ Denote the images of $X,Y$ in $A$ as $\bar{X},\bar{Y}$ respectively. Let $\phi \colon A \to A$ be a ring homomorphism such that

- $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$;
- $\phi(X) = \bar{Y}$;
- $\phi(Y) = 1 - \bar{X} - \bar{Y}.$

The question asks me to show that there is only one possible choice for $\phi.$ I'm not sure how I'm supposed to approach this.

Certainly, $\phi$ is a well-defined homomorphism as it respects the quotients, i.e. $\phi(X^2Y+XY^2-XY) = 0.$ Also, if we consider $\phi(X+Y+i^2),$ we have that $$\phi(X+Y+i^2) = \phi(X+Y-1) = -\bar{X}$$ and $$\phi(X+Y+i^2) = \phi(X) + \phi(Y) + \phi(i)^2 = 1-\bar{X}+\phi(i)^2.$$ So $\phi(i)^2 = -1,$ i.e. $\phi$ is either the identity or conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$. However, how can I show that conjugation does not give us a ring homomorphism?

I'm not sure if it helps in this question, but the previous part asked me to list the prime ideals of $A,$ which I hope are $(X)\ ,(Y),\ (X+Y-1),\ (X,Y),$ and $(X-a,Y+a-1)$ for any $a\in\mathbb{C}.$

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You only proved that $\phi(i)^2= -1$, not that $\phi$ is the identity or the conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$ : what about the real numbers ?

Comment: @Max right, forgot about those.. that makes matters a lot worse for me..

Comment: This corresponds to 3 lines cut out by the equation and indicates you should use CRT to look at lines first.

Comment: Are you sure that this is all you have in the problem statement?  The map $\bar{\varphi}:A\to A$ sending $z\in \mathbb{C}$ to $\bar{z}$, $\bar{X}\mapsto \bar{Y}$, and $\bar{Y}\mapsto 1-\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$ does extend to a ring endomorphism of $A$.  In fact, if you let $\alpha$ be any field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ (and there are uncountably many of such $\alpha$), then $\alpha$ can be extended to a ring endomorphism of $A$ with $\alpha(\bar{X})=\bar{Y}$ and $\alpha(\bar{Y})=1-\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$.  Thus, your $\varphi$ is certainly not unique with the required properties.

Comment: On the other hand, if the problem statement says that $\varphi$ is the *identity* on $\mathbb{C}$, then yes, $\varphi$ is unique, almost trivially.

Comment: @Batominovski Indeed, that is what I thought as well. Perhaps the problem is just erroneous..